# Why is brightness dimmed when I unplug my Samsung laptop RV509 laptop?

Tags: brightness

I'm using a Samsung laptop RV509. Brightness is dimmed when I unplug the laptop. Even the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are not working for brightness but it works for volume. What can I do to get a brighter display on battery?

Comment: are you able to change brightness from `Power Options` ?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Battery icon in the System Tray and go to "Power Options". See which power plan you are running presently. Click on "Change Plan Settings" and see the screen brightness levels when the system is plugged in/charging and when the system is running on battery power. Most likely, the brightness settings for these two conditions will be different in your plan.